# How can I put my list item onto the next open line?

Tags: html, css, forms

So my code is this:

```css
.bottombarelementL {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.bottombarelementL:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bottombarelementR {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.bottombarelementR:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomnavleft">
  <ul class="bottomleft">
    <li class="bottombarelementL">About Us</li>
    <li class="bottombarelementL">Affiliates</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="bottomnavright">
  <ul class="bottomright">
    <li class="bottombarelementR">TOS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the navbar to go onto the next line. I want the bottom nav to be like 2 rows of text. Sorry I am new to coding html css and Im only 13 and Im trying to improve. I am open to any help and support you can give me!
[I want the bottom texts to be in 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKvqB.jpg)

Comment: you want it in 2 rows like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h9k5exry/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) view,

You need to add `display: flex` to the parent. And add `flex ratio` to the children.

**Example**

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='nav'>
  <div class='left'>
    <ul>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Affiliates</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    <ul>
      <li>TOS</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: uhh it didnt work, they just all went towards the right side of the screen